# Простой скрип js select

Tags: javascript, select

```html
<select id="selectId" name="type">
        <option name="first" value="1">1</option>
        <option  name="second" value="2">2</option>
    </select>

<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="ОК" />
```

Нужен js скрипт при нажатии на ок  если выбрано 1 то выводит   ниже  1 если выбрано 2 то выводит и 1 и 2

Comment: а сами что-то пробовали писать ?

Answer (score 1):

Просто достаем все `options` в цикле бежим по ним и выводим все по о череди, когда видим выбраный `option` перестаем выводить (выбран или нет определяем по наличию атрибута [`selected`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp))

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("submit");
var select = document.getElementById("selectId");
var res = document.getElementById("result");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var o = select.options;
  res.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    if (o[i].selected) {
      res.innerHTML += o[i].value + ';';
      break;
    } else {
      res.innerHTML += o[i].value + ', ';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectId" name="type">
    <option name="first" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="second" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="third" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="forth" value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="ОК" />

<p>
  Выбрано: <span id="result"><i>ничего</i></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML
        = document.getElementById("selectId").value;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectId" name="type">
    <option name="first" value="1">1</option>
    <option  name="second" value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit"  value="ОК" />

<p>
    Выбрано: <span id="result"><i>ничего</i></span>
</p>
```

Добавили область для вывода, повесили на кнопку обработчик щелчка, в котором присваиваем значение из выпадающего списка.

Comment: Перечитай вопрос, ему надо, что бы при выборе 2 выводились оба и 1 и 2